# Don't know how to approach $x \cos(x) - 2 \cos^2(x) = 2$

Tags: trigonometry

I don't how to solve for $x$ because of the mixture of trig and $x$ outside a trig function. Can someone give me a hint how to proceed?
$$x \cos(x) - 2 \cos^2(x) = 2$$ where the interval is $[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Hint: May not have solution in the interval $[0,2\pi]$?  Just a possibility.

Comment: I know there is an answer for the interval, but I didn't know how to get it.

Comment: $5.2008013281450192338$ is not recognized by the ISC http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is both inside and outside of trigonometric functions, don't look for an explicit solution in  ̲g̲e̲n̲e̲r̲a̲l̲ ̲c̲a̲s̲e̲.

You should use numerical methods in such cases.

If you just look for the answer and the solution method is not important to you, here is the [wolfram link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20cos%28x%29%20-%202%28cos%28x%29%29%5E2%3D2) showing that there is a root $x\approx5.2$ in this interval.

First note that for nonzero $\cos x$, this reduces to $$x=2\Big(\cos x + \frac{1}{\cos x}\Big)$$ where the right hand side lies in the interval $(-\infty, -4]\cup [4, \infty)$ from the *AM-GM* inequality. Hence, positive $x$ must be greater than 4. Additionally see that for $f(x) = x\cos x-(2\cos^2 x+2)$, $f(0)=-4 <0$ and $f(2\pi)\approx 2.28 > 0$. Hence, by the intermediate value theorem,$f(x)$ must have a root in $(0, 2\pi)$. So, a root lies in $[4,2\pi)$. Next, use numerical methods to find the root.

The best method is to iterate. A possible starting value is $x_1 = 5$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

$$f(x)=x \cos(x) - 2 \cos^2(x) - 2$$

$$f'(x)=-x \sin(x)+2 \sin(2 x)+\cos(x)$$

Stop when $x_n = x_{n-1}$

[more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Description).

---

And [here](https://ideone.com/Yx3j5r) there is a C++ code for the implementation. As you see the output result is $x=5.200801328145019$ you can increase the precision.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Isn't the root $x \doteq 5.2$ in that interval?

Comment: @BrianTung you are right.

Comment: That's my understanding.

Comment: @JohnnyB Someone post a numerical approximation answer for you?

Comment: Thank you, but I really want to know how to do the numerical method. I knew the answer, it was the method of solving the problem that I needed. Now I know there is no simple method.

Comment: @JohnnyB, please see my updated answer.

Comment: And [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u-Gc--*G.tG1y^.tG1+2+2%2B-.tG1*G.tG0y.tyG00&debug=0) is a Pyth code for you :)

Comment: Thanks to all who responded to my question. I see now what I must do and how to do it. Wonderful first experience here.

Comment: @Arashium. I fixed subscripts in the formula for Newton iterates. I hope you don't mind. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnnyB Please accept this answer if you think this reasonably answered your question.

Comment: @JohnnyB There is a grey coloured tick mark beside each answer, below the upvote-downvote buttons. Pressing that should turn it into a green tick, which means this answer has been accepted. You'll gain some reputation points too.

Comment: @AritraDas It's done. Thank you.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks, take it easy.